# Removing prefix from strings in R data frame

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have a data frame, `wkt_small` with the following data:

```
id             GEOMETRY                                                                                      
  <chr>          <chr>                                                                                         
1 PTK01        LINESTRING( 1.142 85.892 1.400, 0.991 85.892 1.400)
2 PTK02        LINESTRING( 2.142 85.892 1.400, 0.991 85.892 1.400)
...
```

What I need is it to look like this:

```
id             GEOMETRY                                                                                      
  <chr>          <chr>                                                                                         
1 PTK01        ( 1.142 85.892 1.400, 0.991 85.892 1.400)
2 PTK02        ( 2.142 85.892 1.400, 0.991 85.892 1.400)
...
```

I have tried the following:

```
wkt_small[, 2] <- gsub('^\\w+', '', wkt_small[, 2])
```

This however gives me the following value for `GEOMETRY` for all rows:

```
("LINESTRING( 1.142 85.892 1.400, 0.991 85.892 1.400, 0.991 85.301 1.4)","LINESTRING( 1.142 85.892 1.400, 0.991 85.892 1.400, 0.991 85.301 1.4)"...
```

concatenating the first row value with the string I want removed for all entries in the data frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[[…]]` or `$…` to select a single column, not `[, …]`:

```
wkt_small$GEOMETRY <- sub('^\\w+', '', wkt_small$GEOMETRY)
```

… actually, with a proper `data.frame` your code would have worked as well; but with a tibble, `[` indexing *always returns a tibble*, not a column vector. The tibble semantics are equivalent of using `[, …, drop = FALSE]` with a regular `data.frame`.

Comment: I would rather suggest to use `sub` instead of `gsub` in this case, since only one part of the whole string is being replaced

Comment: @Onyambu Yes, I strongly agree (and usually leave such comments ;-)).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph which regex is better:  `gsub('^\\w+', '', wkt_small$GEOMETRY)` vs. `gsub("^.*?\\(","\\(", wkt_small$GEOMETRY)`? Thank you.

Comment: @TarJae Depends on what exactly what you want to match. But in general I prefer being as specific as possible. So maybe `"^\\w+\\("`. Anyway, heed the comment above and use `sub` instead of `gsub`.

Answer (score 1):

Update:
We could use `str_remove` (which is better in this case):

```
library(stringr)
wkt_small %>% 
    mutate(GEOMETRY = str_remove(GEOMETRY, '^\\w+'))
```

We could use `str_replace` from `stringr` package with regular expression `"^[A-Z]*"`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    mutate(GEOMETRY = str_replace(GEOMETRY, "^[A-Z]*", ""))
```

Output:

```
  id    GEOMETRY                                 
  <chr> <chr>                                    
1 PTK01 ( 1.142 85.892 1.400, 0.991 85.892 1.400)
2 PTK02 ( 2.142 85.892 1.400, 0.991 85.892 1.400)
```